# failed to create MediaExtractor while trying to setDataSource ,is there any solution?

Tags: android

I am trying to get the number of channels for the file which is located in my app's data dir,

```
fun getChannelCount( path: String?): Int {
    path ?: return 0
    val mediaExtractor = MediaExtractor()
    mediaExtractor.setDataSource(path)
    val trackFormat = mediaExtractor.getTrackFormat(0)
    return  trackFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT)
}
```

the Exception i got ->

```
initMediaExtractor: failed to create MediaExtractor
```

2023-11-13 14:46:28.952 25469-25469 AndroidRuntime          com.example.audo                     E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main (Ask Studio Bot)
Process: com.example.audo, PID: 25469
java.io.IOException: Failed to instantiate extractor.
at android.media.MediaExtractor.nativeSetDataSource(Native Method)
at android.media.MediaExtractor.setDataSource(MediaExtractor.java:203)
at com.example.audo.util.FileUtil.getChannelCount(FileUtil.kt:18)
at com.example.audo.ui.screens.HomeScreenKt$HomeScreen$pickFile$1$1$1.invoke(HomeScreen.kt:74)
at com.example.audo.ui.screens.HomeScreenKt$HomeScreen$pickFile$1$1$1.invoke(HomeScreen.kt:72)
at c.a$c.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:2)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8762)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@a7a4873, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]